# Log delete rows in certain tables | backup deleted data

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I want to log **deleted** data from certain tables. That from logs I could recover the deleted data. Mysql supports something similar out of the box? Ideally, get a sql file with "insert".

Answer (score 1):

There is a partial solution. 
For every table you want to audit, create BEFORE DELETE trigger and an audit table. See code below.

Keep in mind that triggers work only for DELETE FROM command. 
TRUNCATE bypass triggers and your deletes will not be audited.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER table1_before_delete
BEFORE DELETE
   ON table1 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO table1_audit ( table1_id, deleted_date) VALUES ( OLD.id, NOW());

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```